# iOS Unit Testing of Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unit-testing

I am working on unit testing of one custom `UITableviewCell`(TrasmitCell) data , We have inbuild labels in `UITableviewCell`, textLabel and DetailTextLabel, Instead of that I Created one custom cell and displayed in my tableview. now I want to test the data passed to that custom cell. I am able to get the inbuild methods textLabel and DetailTextLabel but how do i get the content of custom cell `(TrasmitCell)`. custom cell `(TrasmitCell)` has two labels and one image

```
- (void)testTableViewCellsHaveCorrectTextLabel {

NSIndexPath *rowIndex0 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *cell0 = [self.viewControllerUnderTest tableView:self.viewControllerUnderTest.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:rowIndex0];

XCTAssert([cell0.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"abc"], @"ViewController under test is composed of a UITableView that has improperly initialized UITableViewCells");

//Instead of cell0.textLabel.text m looking for data from custom tableview cell objects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try apple UI testing — [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-406/)

Also you can try [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)

UI testing - not unit testing. Unit testing (XCT) you can use only working with data (for example if you compute input data and keep result in label).